# Does a database backup include all files?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

If I have two files in my database (mdf & ndf), when I do a backup of the database with the statement:

```
backup database mydb;
```

are both the two files are backed up?

Comment: why dont your try it to test it yourself ? I am voting to close this question, since this is something you can try and educate yourself. BTW, you need to specify backup location as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does .bak file also contain backup of ldf file?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106164/does-bak-file-also-contain-backup-of-ldf-file)

Answer (score 10):

Yes. Details here: [Backup Overview (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175477(v=sql.105).aspx)

This is the section relevant for you:

- Full backup

  A *full backup* contains all the data in a specific database or set of filegroups or files, and also enough log to allow for recovering that data.

You should always *test* the backup (ideally by performing a restore to another location) to ensure you can recover your data in the event of a disaster.